How to prevent multiple browser pop up for snowflake connection when using externalbrowser authentication?
I'm using Snowflake.Data.Client; to connect to snowflake in C#.
sfConnString = @"account=MY_ACCOUNT;authenticator=externalbrowser;database=MY_DB;warehouse=MY_WH;role=My_ROLE;

This is my method to run queries:
    public static void SnowflakeQuery(string query)
    {
        using (SnowflakeDbConnection conn = new(sfConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SnowflakeDbCommand cmd = new();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

This works but every time I call SnowflakeQuery method, a browser pop-up happens before the query runs. How do I make it so I only need to authenticate once per session? Kinda like the Snowflake extension on VS Code.


Hi, Establish the snowflake connection only once and executes the query using cursor method on top snowflake connection. With this approach it will open the external browser only once. I am not familiar with Java if you need let me know I can share the python logic

I figured it out. I just had to move the SnowflakeDbConnection object out of the method so it doesn't create a new connection each time.
readonly private static SnowflakeDbConnection conn = new(sfConnString)

public static void SnowflakeQuery(string query)
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed || conn.State == ConnectionState.Broken) conn.Open();
    SnowflakeDbCommand cmd = new();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}


Be careful with static objects because they can be used by multiple threads concurrently - you don't seem to be using any locking primitives - are you sure SnowflakeDbConnection is thread-safe?

Thanks for the advice, I will take a look and adjust my code accordingly. EDIT: according to the official doc, it is thread-safe!

Whenever a client application establishes a new connection to Snowflake, the user is prompted for authentication. If the client application establishes a connection multiple times, this can result in multiple prompts for authentication.
The account administrator can enable connection caching to minimize the number of times a user is prompted for authentication. When connection caching is enabled, the client application stores a connection token for use in subsequent connections.
To enable connection caching:
Set the account-level parameter ALLOW_ID_TOKEN to true:
alter account set allow_id_token = true;
For more information refer-
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use#using-connection-caching-to-minimize-the-number-of-prompts-for-authentication-optional
